# MySQL SELECT users don't bought products

Tags: mysql

How can I find users don't bought products by specific date?
I have three tables:

USERS
id, name, surname, email

PRODUCTS
id, name, description

TRANSACTIONS
id, id_user, id_product, date

I would like to know users doesn't bought products with id 1,3,4 in the last 3 months for example.

I've tried with these:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN transactions t ON u.id = t.id_user 
WHERE t.id_product != 1 AND t.id_product != 3 AND t.id_product != 4 
AND t.date >= "2019-04-01";

SELECT u.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN transactions t ON u.id = t.id_user 
WHERE t.id_product NOT IN(1,3,4) AND t.date >= "2019-04-01";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LEFT JOIN` will work if you set the conditions in the `ON` clause and select only the non matching rows from the table `transactions`:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN transactions t 
ON u.id = t.id_user AND t.date >= '2019-04-01' AND t.id_product IN (1, 3, 4)
WHERE t.id_user IS NULL
```

Also NOT EXISTS works:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM transactions t
  WHERE u.id = t.id_user AND t.date >= '2019-04-01' AND t.id_product IN (1, 3, 4)
)
```